# How to change touch position when passing a UITouch object?

Tags: iphone, uitouch

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  if(touchDelegate_)
  {

    // before passing the event, I want to scale touch position by 2, how can i do it?

    // that is, if touch position is (5, 5), I want touchDelegate_ see it as (10, 10)        

    [touchDelegate_ touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. `UITouch` is a readonly object. There is no public API that allows you to manipulate it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. That means there's no way to do it transparently without modifying existing code? What a pity.

Comment: Generally, if you don't handle the touches, it is passed onto the next responder. So what kind of delegation do you want to do and to whom do you want to delegate to?

Comment: Before passing onto any responder, I want it scaled by 2, that's all. By the way, I'm solving iPhone/iPad resolution compatible issue, that's one of the aspects.